# SSH Permission Denied; Trying to access host in intranet

Tags: windows, ssh, permission-denied

I know there are several "SHH Permission Denied" questions out there but noting really worked for me. 
I am trying to connect to my raspberry pi (Rasbian Butcher) from my PC (Windows 10; Version 1903) using ssh but I get following error:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user_name/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "smarthome" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to smarthome [192.168.178.24] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10013, io:0000024AC4D4EAA0
debug1: connect to address 192.168.178.24 port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host host_name port 22: Permission denied
```

I already tried reseting my firewall to default, to deactivate it, to reinstall ssh server and client on windows.

Does any of you has another idea?

I should add: 
-ssh is enabled
-I can access the same raspberry pi with a linux machine on the same network so it must be somehow a win10 probelm

Comment: I don't know if that helps but ssh is disabled on Raspbian by default. To enable it you just have to create an empty file called ssh in the boot partition.

Comment: enabled ssh and as I added above (really should have done that earlier, sry for that) I can reach the pi with a linux machine